# python auto clears everything on screen after 298 lines

Tags: python

my problem is that python.exe auto clears everything ive printed to it, after a certain amount of lines has been reached, for example i created the following program

```
a = 0
for a in range(0, 10000):
   print(str(a) + ':> cola')

delay = input('BLARG :>')
```

now when i ran this in python .exe, i got the following result.
[IMAGE1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkB2W.png), and it carried on like this till it reached the end. [IMAGE2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSZy4.png) now the problem is python erased everything in the first image that came before the 9701st print which is a tad troublesome, does anyone have any advice on how to prevent python auto clearing everything.

Comment: This is not a python problem. change settings of your console.

Comment: how do i do that, do i have to go into the binary files or something

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... Do you simply want to say that older lines are disappearing when next are coming?

Comment: yeah, they arent erased, you just cant view them any more, in idle theyre still visible

Comment: this might help http://superuser.com/questions/378313/windows-command-prompt-how-do-i-increase-my-buffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is not a python problem. change settings of your console ~v1k45

Windows' CMD you're using have a limit of old output it remembers.

<sub>I don't have Windows in English, so I do translation of names of the options myself, and they can differ from reality.</sub>

To change the limit, right-click on it's title bar and select *Properties* (for current window, or *Defaults* to change it for all future cmd windows), go to the tab *Layout* and increase heigth of *Buffer size*:

[image: Increasing height of buffer size]